# Convert matrix into value pairs with awk

Tags: awk

I have a matrix of data with latitude longitude and temperature on the following format:

```
            15W     14.5W   14W     13.5W   13W 
30N         19.3    19.3    19.2    18.9    18.6
30.5N       19.1    19      19      18.9    18.4
31N         18.9    18.8    18.7    18.6    18.3
31.5N       18.9    18.7    18.7    18.6    18.1
32N         18.6    18.5    18.6    18.5    17.5
```

I would like to use awk to convert it into lines with latitude longitude and temperature.
The output should look like this:

```
15W 30N 19.3 
15W 30.5N 19.1 
15W 31N 18.9 
15W 31.5N 18.9 
15W 32N 18.6
14.5W 30N 19.3
14.5W 30.5N 19
14.5W 31N 18.8
```

I guess you get the idea. I thought about awk because I have done some other things with it and it was very powerful. But maybe some other tools are to be used here.

The number of rows and columns is not always the same.

I will also need to convert the latitude and longitude to decimal minutes, but I'm taking one step at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

awk one-liner (well a bit long maybe):

```
 awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)t[i]=$i}{ r[NR]=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) v[t[i-1],$1]=$i}END{for(i=1;i<=length(t);i++) for(j=2;j<=NR;j++) print t[i], r[j], v[t[i],r[j]]
} ' file
```

I would like to format above one-liner into "three-liners" :) :

```
 awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)t[i]=$i}
        { r[NR]=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) v[t[i-1],$1]=$i}
        END{for(i=1;i<=length(t);i++)for(j=2;j<=NR;j++)print t[i], r[j], v[t[i],r[j]]} ' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat t
            15W     14.5W   14W     13.5W   13W 
30N         19.3    19.3    19.2    18.9    18.6
30.5N       19.1    19      19      18.9    18.4
31N         18.9    18.8    18.7    18.6    18.3
31.5N       18.9    18.7    18.7    18.6    18.1
32N         18.6    18.5    18.6    18.5    17.5

kent$  awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)t[i]=$i}
        { r[NR]=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) v[t[i-1],$1]=$i}
        END{for(i=1;i<=length(t);i++)for(j=2;j<=NR;j++)print t[i], r[j], v[t[i],r[j]]} ' t
15W 30N 19.3
15W 30.5N 19.1
15W 31N 18.9
15W 31.5N 18.9
15W 32N 18.6
14.5W 30N 19.3
14.5W 30.5N 19
14.5W 31N 18.8
14.5W 31.5N 18.7
14.5W 32N 18.5
14W 30N 19.2
14W 30.5N 19
14W 31N 18.7
14W 31.5N 18.7
14W 32N 18.6
13.5W 30N 18.9
13.5W 30.5N 18.9
13.5W 31N 18.6
13.5W 31.5N 18.6
13.5W 32N 18.5
13W 30N 18.6
13W 30.5N 18.4
13W 31N 18.3
13W 31.5N 18.1
13W 32N 17.5
```

Comment: Wow, it works great. Thanks a lot. I thought maybe I was a bit rusty with awk, but even in my best days that's way out of my league. There's one thing I forgot, some temperature values are errors, they are 999.9, I would like to ignore those, any idea about where to insert the if for that?

Comment: @PRN you could add an "if" statement in the END block, e.g. if v[t[i],r[j]] < range , then print. if you could not manage to work it out, add the new condition in your question, I could do a update on my answer.

Comment: That was more than enough, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The solution doesn't need to be complicated. It's actually fairly straightforward once you've chosen the right data structure. Simply use `GNU awk` to employ a true multidimensional array. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
NR==1 {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        a[i]=$i
    }
    next
}

{
    for (j=2;j<=NF;j++) {
        b[j-1][NR]["rec"] = a[j-1] FS $1 FS $j
        b[j-1][NR]["val"] = $j
    }
}

END {
    for (x=1;x<=length(b);x++) {
        for (y=2;y<=NR;y++) {

            if (b[x][y]["val"] != "999.9") {

                print b[x][y]["rec"] | "column -t"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
15W    30N    19.3
15W    30.5N  19.1
15W    31N    18.9
15W    31.5N  18.9
15W    32N    18.6
14.5W  30N    19.3
14.5W  30.5N  19
14.5W  31N    18.8
14.5W  31.5N  18.7
14.5W  32N    18.5
14W    30N    19.2
14W    30.5N  19
14W    31N    18.7
14W    31.5N  18.7
14W    32N    18.6
13.5W  30N    18.9
13.5W  30.5N  18.9
13.5W  31N    18.6
13.5W  31.5N  18.6
13.5W  32N    18.5
13W    30N    18.6
13W    30.5N  18.4
13W    31N    18.3
13W    31.5N  18.1
13W    32N    17.5
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==1 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=$i; next } { for (j=2;j<=NF;j++) { b[j-1][NR]["rec"] = a[j-1] FS $1 FS $j; b[j-1][NR]["val"] = $j } } END { for (x=1;x<=length(b);x++) for (y=2;y<=NR;y++) if (b[x][y]["val"] != "999.9") print b[x][y]["rec"] | "column -t" }' file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve, this approach also seems to work great, and it already includes the discrimination of wrong data, so thanks to you too.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1{n=split($0,a," ")}NR!=1{for(i=1;i<=n;i++)x[a[i]" "$1]=$(i+1);}END{for(i in x){print i,x[i]}}' temp | sort
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
            15W     14.5W   14W     13.5W   13W 
30N         19.3    19.3    19.2    18.9    18.6
30.5N       19.1    19      19      18.9    18.4
31N         18.9    18.8    18.7    18.6    18.3
31.5N       18.9    18.7    18.7    18.6    18.1
32N         18.6    18.5    18.6    18.5    17.5
phoenix.250> nawk 'NR==1{n=split($0,a," ")}NR!=1{for(i=1;i<=n;i++)x[a[i]" "$1]=$(i+1);}END{for(i in x){print i,x[i]}}' temp | sort
13.5W 30.5N 18.9
13.5W 30N 18.9
13.5W 31.5N 18.6
13.5W 31N 18.6
13.5W 32N 18.5
13W 30.5N 18.4
13W 30N 18.6
13W 31.5N 18.1
13W 31N 18.3
13W 32N 17.5
14.5W 30.5N 19
14.5W 30N 19.3
14.5W 31.5N 18.7
14.5W 31N 18.8
14.5W 32N 18.5
14W 30.5N 19
14W 30N 19.2
14W 31.5N 18.7
14W 31N 18.7
14W 32N 18.6
15W 30.5N 19.1
15W 30N 19.3
15W 31.5N 18.9
15W 31N 18.9
15W 32N 18.6
>
```